# JSON parse the fields which user wants in Django REST API framework

Tags: json, django, django-rest-framework, jsonparser

I want to make users to be able to change some values of the object. For example, there is an event with ID "Id1" at "20.12.2021 14:00:00+00:00", a title of the event "the title", a description - "the description" and participants of the event ["Anne", "Jean", "Eren", "Sasha", "ME"].
I need to write a view which allows a user to change/update any of this values. If he wants, he can change only datetime, or only participants, or only title, or datetime AND title, or all the fields at once(although it is better to create a new event if it is needed to change everything in the first event, but anyways). So I need to know how to write a view which allows user to JSON parse only the fields he wants.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a model serializer to serialize your Event objects and the view class can use this serializer. Check out Django Rest Framework's docs https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer